# Creating Filters/Facets on Filtered Results

Tags: solr, faceted-search, searchfiltercollection

I have a JS code that gets results from SOLR (v8.3.x). I have a few select boxes that get populated based on the facets I receive from SOLR. The problem is that since I create options based on the results I get, the user needs to remove the filter first to change the filter. Ideally, he/she should be able to just change the option in the select box. Also, the complication is that I need filters to be interdependent.

Example:
User selects gender "female".
All the results have only "female" as the option for "gender", so select box has only "female" as the option.
Also, since the filters are interdependent, if there is no "female" who is from "India", the option shouldn't be there for the other select box for "country".

This should be a very basic thing in computing, I see so many sites doing it fine. What am I missing? Any concept I should read on?

Comment: Check tagging and excluding filter. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/faceting.html#tagging-and-excluding-filters

Comment: Glad I could help.